# f:setPropertyActionListener not setting the property in p:datatable

Tags: primefaces

**SOLUTION**
Long story short, `"not empty #{pastTxModel.currentTx.xml}"` should be `"#{not empty pastTxModel.currentTx.xml}"`. Yeah, I know...

**UPDATE**
The problem is here:

```
<p:inputTextarea id="test" value="#{pastTxModel.currentTx.xml}" rendered="not empty #{pastTxModel.currentTx.xml}"></p:inputTextarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story but the solution is -

Part 1-

```
<h:form id="alltxform">
    <p:dataTable id="tablealltx" var="transaction" value="#{transactionListModel.txList}">    
        <p:column>
            <p:commandButton update=":alltxform:xmlDetail" action="#{transactionListModel.setSelectedTx(transaction)}">  
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

    <p:dialog header="Detail" widgetVar="dialog">
        <p:outputPanel id="xmlDetail">
            <p:inputTextarea id="test" value="#{pastTxModel.currentTx.xml}" rendered="not empty #{pastTxModel.currentTx.xml}"></p:inputTextarea>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:dialog> 
</h:form>
```

Then Change -

```
<p:inputTextarea id="test" value="#{pastTxModel.currentTx.xml}" rendered="not empty #{pastTxModel.currentTx.xml}"></p:inputTextarea>
```

To -

```
<p:inputTextarea id="test" value="#{pastTxModel.currentTx.xml}" rendered="#{not empty pastTxModel.currentTx.xml}"></p:inputTextarea>
```

Comment: I used action="#{pastTxModel.selectedTx(transaction)}", but the selectedTx stays null

Comment: Access it through the bean - controllerBean.pastTxMode‌​l.selectedTx(transact‌​ion) - Does the transaction definitely have a value?

Comment: Sorry your bean is transactionListModel - so change to transactionListModel.setSelectedTx(transaction)

Comment: I renamed them, it's the same. For some reason, the selectedTx is not set. The txList is fine.

Comment: Even with a dedicated method in the controller, the model is not updated:  public void setSelectedTx(TransactionVO vo){
  pastTxModel.setSelectedTx(vo);
 }

Comment: Something must be wrong, my setters are not even called. Back to debugging :(

Comment: Yeah Im confused - Im looking at a similar implementation and its populating with no problems.It could be scope related or your looking at the wrong bean? Try removing update=":alltxform:xmlDetail"

Comment: Rename your bean to @ManagedBean as that is what should be used for JSF

Comment: No, I am using CDI beans. This is unrelated to my problem: http://germanescobar.net/2010/04/4-areas-of-possible-confusion-in-jee6.html

Comment: Now my setter is called, but the p:inputTextarea is not rendered because #{pastTxModel.currentTx.xml} is empty (?!)

Comment: Updated the first post.

Comment: is the syntax not - rendered="#{not empty pastTxModel.currentTx.xml}"?

Comment: Holy crap. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the whole dialog after clicking on the button.

```
<p:commandButton update=":alltxform:Detail" oncomplete="PF('dialog').show()">  
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{transaction}"
                    target="#{transactionListModel.selectedTx}" />  
        </p:commandButton>
```

Comment: That did not change anything